# how to integrate google map in php & mark places with flags

Tags: php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I intergrate google map in php and mark the places there in the map dynamically. I want to show areas with specific details from database to google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library: [PHP Easy Google Map](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3801-PHP-Display-world-locations-using-Google-maps.html). It can:

- Define the map width, height and zoom level
- **Add one or more marker to locations on the map using their addresses**
- Use several types of predefined **icons and colors to mark locations**
- Define the information window text and link URLs associated to a location

Comment: will check and get back to you

Comment: thanks its good sample but `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\Users\logon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\google map as input\google\SampleGmaps.php on line 3` a small warning and this is line no.3 **`$gm = & new EasyGoogleMap("ABQIAAAAoM-kEW8yHxWwveOZAouVXhTkQdzC1XuexHlQDsWmu58XcfHJ8xQB-xtA9nt_7NDWTsfJfHHxosdNZg");`**